# How do i get my regex to replace lowercase to uppercase with additional variables

Tags: javascript, regex, expression, uppercase

I have an app that in the UK POSTCODE i want the client to type in their postcode and several things happen...
1) i only allows A-Z and 0-9
2) only space is allowed as special character

Im getting what i want except that it allows upper and lowercase

I know that the /i allows any case so please dont point this out. If i remove it and the client types in for example "sw10 9ef" they are not paying attention to whats being typed in and were getting "10 9" for customers who use lowercase but correct who uses uppercase "SW10 9EF"

Any help would be appreciated

Lee

```
<script>
function postOnly(input) {
    var regex = /[^0-9A-Z ]/gi;
    input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}
</script>




<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 control-label"><i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt fa-lg"></i> Postal Code ( ZZZZ XXX or ZZZ XXX ) 
</label>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('postal_code'); ?>" name="postal_code" onkeyup="postOnly(this)" class="form-control" placeholder="Postal Code ( ZZZZ XXX or ZZZ XXX )">
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So i need it to change the case from lower to upper live whilst keeping the above requirements.

Comment: Have you tried `str.toUpperCase()`?

Comment: Give the user a break, is there an actual place with zip `SW10 9EF` and then there;s another location called: `sw10 9ef`?...Nope there's only one "Finborough Road, London SW10 9EF" place in the world...

Comment: the postcode is one a real one, Its one of the clients post codes of the users

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using the front end of your application to add restrictions to the incoming data, or at least not only the front end, as it's trivial to bypass. Taking that on board your front end should really not care weather or not a user is using upper or lower case letters in a postcode and the back end should convert lower case letters to upper case ones before further processing.

You can add a `text-transform:uppercase` style to the input box so that what ever the user types *appears* to be in upper case, but that is only a visual styling and if the user inputs the postcode in lower case then it will be returned to the back end application as lower case letters.

Comment: I did try this, but i had some strange results, when typing in the case does indeed force capital letters, but when your check the mysql db its displaying sw10 9EF a mixture of caps and lower so i scrapped that

and you are right about the front end, but this is a practice exercise for a bunch of old ladies bridge club lol so not too fussed about it being manipulated. Just the club president has asked for the query printout to be formatted better thus me being here after hours of googling

Comment: There is an upper() function in SQL that you could use to convert the data to upper case in your insert statement

Comment: oh i wasnt aware of this, i could set a cron job to force this on the nightly

Comment: If you have access to the code doing the insert it would be simpler to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You should check:

1. Your regex allow both uppercase and lowercase characters.
2. After checking that your input value is correct as per your requirements convert your input value to upper case.

   ```
   var regex=/[^0-9A-Za-z ]/g;
   if(input.value.match(regex)){
        input.value=input.value.toUpperCase();
   }
   ```

Comment: I have copied this into the function but now im getting anything allowed to be typed into the field..

    <code>
    function postOnly(input) {
        var regex=/[^0-9A-Za-z ]/g;
        if(input.value.match(regex)){
        input.value=input.value.toUpperCase();
    }
    }
    </code>